# I am not able to add image texture to this cube. I get a green distorted cube. I dont know what is the problem

Tags: android, opengl-es

```
package edu.dhbw.andar.sample;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;

import edu.dhbw.andar.ARObject;
import edu.dhbw.andar.pub.SimpleBox;
import edu.dhbw.andar.util.GraphicsUtil;

/**
 * An example of an AR object being drawn on a marker.
 * @author tobi
 *
 */
public class CustomObject extends ARObject {

    int[] texture;
    private static final int TEX_SIZE=64; 
      int tex;
      ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
      byte[] b;
      float texCoords1[] = {0f, 0f,20f,20f};
      FloatBuffer texCoords;
    public CustomObject(String name, String patternName,
            double markerWidth, double[] markerCenter) {
        super(name, patternName, markerWidth, markerCenter);
        float   mat_ambientf[]     = {0f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f};
        float   mat_flashf[]       = {0f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f};
        float   mat_diffusef[]       = {0f, 1.0f, 0f, 1.0f};
        float   mat_flash_shinyf[] = {50.0f};

        texCoords= GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(texCoords1);
        mat_ambient = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(mat_ambientf);
        mat_flash = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(mat_flashf);
        mat_flash_shiny = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(mat_flash_shinyf);
        mat_diffuse = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(mat_diffusef);


    }
    public CustomObject(String name, String patternName,
            double markerWidth, double[] markerCenter, float[] customColor) {
        super(name, patternName, markerWidth, markerCenter);
        float   mat_flash_shinyf[] = {50.0f};

        mat_ambient = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(customColor);
        mat_flash = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(customColor);
        mat_flash_shiny = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(mat_flash_shinyf);
        mat_diffuse = GraphicsUtil.makeFloatBuffer(customColor);

    }

    /**
     * Just a box, imported from the AndAR project.
     */
    private SimpleBox box = new SimpleBox();
    private FloatBuffer mat_flash;
    private FloatBuffer mat_ambient;
    private FloatBuffer mat_flash_shiny;
    private FloatBuffer mat_diffuse;

    /**
     * Everything drawn here will be drawn directly onto the marker,
     * as the corresponding translation matrix will already be applied.
     */
    @Override
    public final void draw(GL10 gl) {
        super.draw(gl);


        //draw cube
        try
        {
     //   gl.glColor4f(0, 1.0f, 0, 1.0f);
       // gl.glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, 12.5f );
        if (texture==null)
              texture=new int[1];
          gl.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0);
          Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/Classic_scaled.png");
            int pixels[]=new int[TEX_SIZE*TEX_SIZE];
          bMap.getPixels(pixels, 0, TEX_SIZE, 0, 0, TEX_SIZE, TEX_SIZE);
          int pix1[]=new int[TEX_SIZE*TEX_SIZE];
            for(int i=0; i<TEX_SIZE; i++)
            {
                 for(int j=0; j<TEX_SIZE; j++)
                 {
                      //correction of R and B
                      int pix=pixels[i*TEX_SIZE+j];
                      int pb=(pix>>16)&0xff;
                      int pr=(pix<<16)&0x00ff0000;
                      int px1=(pix&0xff00ff00) | pr | pb;
                      //correction of rows
                      pix1[(TEX_SIZE-i-1)*TEX_SIZE+j]=px1;
                 }
            }     

            IntBuffer tbuf=IntBuffer.wrap(pix1);
            tbuf.position(0);       

          tex = texture[0];
             baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
            bMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); 
             b = baos.toByteArray();

            gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

            gl.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, TEX_SIZE, TEX_SIZE, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tbuf); //I am loading the texture
            gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SPECULAR,mat_flash);
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_SHININESS, mat_flash_shiny);    
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);  
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);

            gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);


        //draw the box
        box.draw(gl);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
             Log.d("error", "IOException e  = " + e.toString());


        }
    }
    @Override
    public void init(GL10 gl) {


    }
}
```

Screenshot: http://blinksolution.com/110504-213626.jpg

Comment: Why not?  What error do you get and from where?  Do you really want us to read through a big block of code and figure it out?  How about some specific questions?

Comment: Also generating and loading a texture every time you want to draw will be as slow as hell.  Can't you just load it once and keep re-using it?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear it. Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry i am not clear. I am not able to add texture to the cube. It is not coming properly.

Comment: A screenshot would also help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to call gl.glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D).

Comment: I have enabled this. so that is not the problem. i get a disorted cube so image is getting maped

Comment: I don't know if this could be the reason but your texCoords are something I have never seen before. From what I've understood they are usually kept within [0f, 1f] range and are mapped to actual texture size during rendering.

Comment: float texCoords1[] = {0f, 0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
(use 1 instead of 20.)